# What is interface f in the route print

Tags: windows, routing

When i type `route print` some interfaces show `f` what exactly is that `f` refer to. Find the attachment, tried searching for manuals, i could only see about `route -f` but i am not able to find anything about this output i get

[image: route print output]

Comment: yes, i get to see only option -f, but nothing about this in the output

Comment: @toto .. `or look at man` ?? this is windows.  Please educate me.